# Pagination in Laravel doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

When i put in my view  {!! $questions->links(); !!} i don't see the pagination style and the page dont take 6 post per page like i put in my controller ..

My post Controller :
class QuestionsController extends Controller {

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{


       $questions = \App\Question::latest()->paginate(6);
               $questions = \App\Question::unsolved();
               $bars     = \App\Question::unsolvedbar();
               $links = str_replace('/?', '?', $questions->render());
       return view('questions.index',compact('questions','bars','links'));
}
```

My Pagination Links in my View: 
{!! $questions->links(); !!}

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris,,
When i put in my view  {!! $questions->links(); !!} i don't see the pagination style and the page dont take 6 post per page like i put in my controller ..

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are overwriting your $questions variable

```
$questions = \App\Question::latest()->paginate(6);
$questions = \App\Question::unsolved();
```

Cant really tell you more without the unsolved() function declaration.

Comment: This the error :
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection' does not have a method 'links' (View: C:\wamp\www\qq\resources\views\questions\index.blade.php)

Comment: Can you provide the declaration code of unsolved() function?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your view:

```
{!! $questions->render() !!}
```

If you want to paginate the links you should do something like this:

```
$links = $questions->links()->paginate();
```

And in the view add:

```
{!! $links->render() !!}
```