# How to paginate in laravel? method paginate doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Trying to get the latest task for each user, so if there is 100 users, I want to get only 10 to display per page but it won't work.
When adding the paginate method I get the following error:

Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.

If I remove the method it all works fine, I get the results expected, I just want to paginate.
This is my code:

```
$users = User::with('latestTask')->get()->paginate(10);
```

Comment: remove `->get()` it should be like `$users = User::with('latestTask')->paginate(10);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pagination in Laravel doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557889/pagination-in-laravel-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not paginate a collection

```
$users = User::with('latestTask')->get();
```

to paginate you should use method paginate() on Eloquent results:

```
$users = User::with('latestTask')->paginate(10);
```

and then in view put the link :

```
{{ $users->links() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method directly, without using `get()`

```
$users = User::with('latestTask')->paginate(10);
```

and in your blade you can get the page links using

`$variable_name->links()`

Answer (score 0):

When you use paginate you then don't need to use **get()**. just follow the the below code as well.

```
$users = User::with('latestTask')->paginate(10);
```

**User** model will automatically handle the request and get number of data given as **argument** in `paginate($number_of_rows)` method.
you can also use  **orderBy()** in as method chaining format like below.

```
$users = User::with('latestTask')->orderBy($column,'asc')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although other answers are right, I wanted to point out the reason behind it...

`get()` executes the query and returns a collection which means you are no longer building/modifying the sql query

`paginate()` should be called on the elequent query itself before it's executed so it can add to the query the offset and limit...

That's why it should be

```
$users = User::with('latestTask')->paginate(10);
```

You can see in the error that 
`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` method paginate doesn't exist because paginate is not a part of the collection

Quoting laravel documentation  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination

> There are several ways to paginate items. The simplest is by using the paginate method on the *&query builder* or an *Eloquent query*